# Rendering a list based on a shared property in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'd like to render out a list of components based on whether the type property is of a certain type. For example, if `resource.type === 'article'` then render all of the resources with type article, etc.

My resources array looks like this

[image]

I have created a component that is basically just a view.

```
<template>
   <div class="type-feed">
       <resource-card></resource-card>
   </div>
</template>

<script>

import Vue from 'vue';
import VueFire from 'vuefire';
import ResourceCard from '../components/ResourceCard'

var resourcesRef = firebase.database().ref('resources');

// explicit installation required in module environments
Vue.use(VueFire);

export default {
    name: 'type-view',
    components: {
      ResourceCard
    },
    data () {
        return {

        }
    },
    firebase: {
        resources: resourcesRef
    }
}

</script>

<style>

</style>
```

The `<resource-card>` component should take in the list and render a specific information on an individual resource object. Something like the following

`<resource-card v-for="(resource, index) in resources" :resource="resource>`

My question is, what is the best way to render a list by `resources.type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `<resource-card>` is not used anywhere else, then just pass the `resource` to it and let it decide what to render according to `resource.type` should be enough.

If you could need a `article` card later elsewhere, or you want a more elegant design, then you may define a component for each resource type, and in the `v-for`, you can use [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) to render different components in one loop.